# Javascript dynamic conditioning

Tags: javascript

I want to build a `IF` condition which is built dynamically based on the parameters it gets. More over, this is expected to be built as a plugin.
For instance, there are 3 parameters for student object, called age,name, phone_numbers. Also, there is a option object for selection parameters.
In the condition,

```
if(student.age >option.age  & student.name == option.name & student.phonenumbers == option.phonenumbers ){
// do stuff 
}
```

If any parameter is missing, it should not be included in the condition. For example, assume, in case option.name is undefined, then the if condition should be prepared as following,

```
if(student.age >option.age & student.phonenumbers == option.phonenumbers ){
    // do stuff 
    }
```

Moreover, why this kind of thing is required is, here an array of (500 objects)  students objects are iterated. The above condition can be splitted into seperat conditions, but then the iteration will be multipled by the number of conditions !!!. So I m looking for a way to add all conditions into one.

However, my approach is, create the expression as a string and then execute it with `eval(..)`,but as far as I know that using `eval` can lead vulnerabilities.

Any one let me know a way to implement a dynamic conditions.

Comment: If «do stuff» doesn't need the parameters, why do you put them in your condition?

Comment: @Joerg. Thanks for your attention. 'doStuff' means something like calculations on student object or add that student obj into an array.

Comment: Are you sure that bit logic would work here?

Comment: Create a function instead, taking parameters and operators to use them. It might even use sandboxed `eval` inside, after making sure the params are valid.

Comment: "The above condition can be splitted into seperat conditions, but then the iteration will be multipled by the number of conditions !!!"... Its the same thing isn't it?? Whether you split the conditions or not. In the end, you either going to have 1,2 or 3 conditions that need to be met, whether you split them up or not

Answer (score 3):

Note that the JavaScript *and* operator is `&&`.

For your example, this should work:

```
if((!student.age || student.age>option.age) && 
   (!student.name || student.name==option.name) &&
   (!student.phonenumbers || student.phonenumbers==option.phonenumbers)
  ) {
}
```

Comment: Drat, that was what I had in mind but was too weirded out to finish so I did it the long way around

Comment: Now I am sort of happy I didn't shorthand it. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function testStudent(student,option) {
  var res = [];
  var test = true;
  if (student.age) res.push(student.age > option.age);
  if (student.name) res.push(student.name == option.name);
  if (student.phonenumbers) res.push(student.phonenumbers == option.phonenumbers);
  for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    test = test && res[i];
  }
  if (res.length > 0 && test) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

generic:

```
function testObjects(obj1,obj2) {

  for (var o in obj1) { // assuming obj2 is a superset of obj1
    if (o === "age" && obj1.age <= obj2.age) return false;
    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(o) && obj1[o] != obj2[o]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
var ok = testObjects(student,option);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is very useful and it could be more decoupled with few modifications, but one more thing to know, assume if there are 100 of students, the for loop will be executed 100 times. Won't there be a solution or have to stick this level ?

Comment: I have made it more generic. An eval could make the second loop/reduce smaller: `var ok = eval(res.join("&&"));`

Comment: The generic function is good, and you can even exclude the `res` and `test` variables.  Within the loop, do something like: `if(o==='age' && obj1.age<=obj2.age) return false; else if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(o) && obj1[o]!=obj2[o]) return false;`  If the loop finishes without returning, you know the objects match.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your conditions in functions and those functions in an Array. so then you can do a loop in the Array and call every function (condition).

```
var aConds = [];
function firstCond(params) {return (params<0)};
function secondCond(params) {return(params!='hi')};
aConds.push(firstCond);
...
for(var i=0;i<aConds.length;i++)
{
  if(!aConds[i](params)) console.log("a condition has not been meet");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it work to allow *undefined* in each condition?

```
if((student.age == undefined || student.age > option.age) && (student.name == undefined || student.name == option.name) ...
```